# (node | io).jsのStreamについて

Tags: javascript, node.js, iojs

jsのStreamについて勉強しています。
readableイベントについて勉強するために
下記のコードを書いたのですが、うまく動きません。

helloworld.txtの内容をconsoleに表示 -> MyPushを付け加える -> process.stdout
(標準出力)に送る

ということがしたいのですが、どうやら、process.stdoutにnullが送られているようです。
どうすればいいのでしょうか?
ちなみに `iojs --harmony_arrow_functions`で動かしています。

```
var Transform = require("stream").Transform;
var util = require("util");
var fs = require("fs");
var StringDecoder = require("string_decoder").StringDecoder;
var process = require("process");
util.inherits(MyStream, Transform);

function MyStream() {
    Transform.call(this);
}


MyStream.prototype._transform = (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
    var data = chunk;
    var utf8decoder = new StringDecoder("utf8");
    var decoded_data = utf8decoder.write(data);
    var send_data = decoded_data + "MyPush\n";
    this.push(send_data);

    callback();
}




var readable_stream = fs.createReadStream("helloworld.txt");
readable_stream.on("readable", () => {
    var chunk = readable_stream.read();
    console.log("Data", chunk);
});

readable_stream.on("end", () => {
    console.log("end");
});
var mystream = new MyStream();
mystream.on("readable", () => {
   var chunk = mystream.read();
    mystream.write(chunk);

})
readable_stream.pipe(mystream).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

おそらくですが...

`read()` メソッドによるデータの読み出しと、`pipe`によるデータの読み出しが衝突しているものと思います。
イベントによって受信したデータを配布する`data`イベントと異なり、`read()`メソッドはキューからデータを取り出します (`readable`はキューにデータが入ってきたことを通知するイベント)。
そのため、誰かがデータを取り出すとキューが空になってしまうのではないかと。

(Node v0.12.2 で実行したところ、逆に `read()` メソッドの結果が `null` でした)

Comment: readで先に読み出して、bufferが空になってしまっているのに、pipeでもう一度読み出そうとしているから、nullが返ってしまうということでしょうか?

Comment: はい。その通りです。