# JavaScriptのstreamでreadするとnullが返ってきてしまう。

Tags: javascript, node.js, iojs

こんにちは、[(node | io).jsのStreamについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9118/node-io-js%E3%81%AEstream%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)の質問をした者です。今、Streamの勉強をしているのですが上記の質問と同じようにhelloworld.txtを読み込み、"MyPush\n"という文字列を追加し、process.stdoutに表示するということを、**pipeを使わず**、代わりにwriteやreadを使って、やってみようと考えています。
しかし、下記のコードを実行すると例のようなエラーが出ます。どうすればいいのでしょうか?

```
var Transform = require("stream").Transform;
var util = require("util");
var fs = require("fs");
var StringDecoder = require("string_decoder").StringDecoder;
var process = require("process");
util.inherits(MyStream, Transform);

function MyStream() {
    Transform.call(this);
}


MyStream.prototype._transform = (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
    var data = chunk;
    var utf8decoder = new StringDecoder("utf8");
    var decoded_data = utf8decoder.write(data);
    var send_data = decoded_data + "MyPush\n";
    this.push(send_data);
    callback();
}




var readable_stream = fs.createReadStream("helloworld.txt");

readable_stream.on("end", () => {
    console.log("end");
});
var mystream = new MyStream();
mystream.on("readable", () => {
    var data = this.read();
    process.stdout.write(data);

});
readable_stream.on("readable", () => {
    var data = readable_stream.read();
    console.log("DATA", data); // return the null
    mystream.write(data);  
});
```

エラーの例

```
_stream_writable.js:263
  var len = state.objectMode ? 1 : chunk.length;
                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:263:41)
    at MyStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:210:11)
    at ReadStream. (/Users/username/jsworks/my_stream2.js:39:14)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:163:7)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:402:7)
    at onEofChunk (_stream_readable.js:385:3)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:129:7)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:109:10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

改めて調べてみました。

Substack 氏によるハンドブックに[詳しい記述](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook#consuming-a-readable-stream)がありました。
ストリーム終端でも `readable` イベントが発生し、この時は `this.read()` が `null` を返す、とのことです。

```
var Transform = require("stream").Transform;
var createReadStream = require("fs").createReadStream;
var inherits = require("util").inherits;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 変換ストリームを定義
function AppendMyPush() {
  Transform.call(this);
}
inherits(AppendMyPush, Transform);

AppendMyPush.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
  // .toString()
  //   chunk が Buffer なら, UTF8でデコードされる。
  //   chunk が string なら, 単に自身を返す。
  // See Also: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end
  //
  // chunk は null ではない
  // See Also: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_transform_transform_chunk_encoding_callback
  this.push(chunk.toString() + "MyPush\n");
  callback();
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ファイルを読んで、変換ストリームを経由して標準出力に書き出す
// source -> append -> sink の順につなぐ
var source = createReadStream("helloworld.txt");
var append = new AppendMyPush();
var sink = process.stdout;

// Readable イベントによってつなげる (source -> append)
source.on("readable", function() {
  console.log("source readable enter");

  // ストリーム終端(これはファイルストリームなのでEOF)でも readable が発生する
  // このとき、this.read() の結果値は null になる
  var chunk = this.read();
  if (chunk != null) {
    console.log("  source readable read:", chunk);
    append.write(chunk);
  }
  else {
    console.log("  source readable reached end");
    // 終端を伝える
    append.end();
  }

  console.log("source readable exit");
});


// Readable イベントによってつなげる (append -> sink)
append.on("readable", function() {
  console.log("  append readable enter");

  var chunk = this.read();
  if (chunk != null) {
    console.log("    append read:", chunk);
    sink.write(chunk);
  }
  else {
    console.log("    append readable reached end");
    // stdout を閉じるべきではない
  }

  console.log("  append readable exit");
});
```

実行結果:

```
source readable enter
  source readable read: <Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 21 0a>
  append readable enter
    append read: <Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 21 0a 4d 79 50 75 73 68 0a>
Hello World!
MyPush
  append readable exit
source readable exit
source readable enter
  source readable reached end
  append readable enter
    append readable reached end
  append readable exit
source readable exit
```

ちなみに、質問で提示されているエラーは、null を受け入れないメソッドである `Writable::write()` に `null` を与えているために発生しています。

Comment: 最後に `null` で `readable` が実行されるのは、引数なしで `this.read()` を使っている時だけかも。
終端は素直に `end` イベントで拾う方が良さそう